# initialize directX using HDC

Tags: directx, window, gdi

does any one know how to initilize directX using hdc? the problem is i want to draw my stuff in a component inside a window and these things usualy only have HDC but DX gets HWND which is assigned to a window.

Comment: What GUI library are you using right now?

Comment: sry i'm using windows sdk and i'm coding using c++

Comment: Huh? You're coding C++ and compiling with GDC?

Comment: my bad i meant HDC(Handle of Device Context)

Comment: Oooh okay, that's **very** different, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an invisible window using CreateWindow with 0 width and 0 height and use that hwnd to create the device. Then you can render the images to a texture, retreive the raw buffer from it and pass it to the application where the image is copied to the window. You do no need the HDC too.

Comment: although i'll probably not use this advise but since that's the best one, you get an accept!

Answer (score 0):

`HDC` represents your rendering device, while `HWND` represents your window.

You can get get an `HDC` representing the Window's rendering target with [`GetDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (don't forget to `ReleaseDC` it when you're done).

Hope that helps?

Comment: the problem is reverse the thing you said, i have HDC in  this case and I need a HWND to pass it for directX initialization

Comment: @Gajet: You can't do that. Where did you get the `HDC` from? You need to get the `HWND` from the same place.

Comment: the HDC is result of calling GetDC(NULL) and i can draw on it using windows Windows GDI but DirectX doesn't accept NULL as HWND

Comment: @Gajet: You're **not** supposed to use `GetDC(NULL)`! Create a window and use that instead; you're not supposed to do DirectX on the entire screen.